# How do JS `localStorage` property descriptors actually work

Tags: javascript, local-storage, standards

Is there any place where it is specified *exactly* how the properties of `localStorage` work? The only thing I found in [the standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage) is:

> `value = storage.getItem (key)`
>
> `value = storage[key]`
>
> Returns the current value associated with the given key, or null if the given key does not exist.
>
> `storage.setItem (key, value)`
>
> `storage[key] = value`
>
> Sets the value of the pair identified by key to value, creating a new key/value pair if none > existed for key previously.

But it doesn’t say anything about what happens if `key` is a special property name like `length` or `setItem` (or `__proto__` or `constructor`).

In practice this seems to work as one would expect: “special” properties work as usual, and only “unused” property names can be accessed with the bracket syntax.

But stuff gets a bit weird if you look at the details. At least on Chrome, if you add a value using as key a “special” property name, like `localStorage.setItem('length', 'test')`, then, somehow, `Object.keys(localStorage)` *does* include `'length'` in the result. Also, if you try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(localStorage)`, `'length'` is included. But if you try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(localStorage)`, no property named `'length'` is returned.

I can’t find any specification, or even description, of how these work. The [ECMA standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours) mentions that “exotic” objects can override “abstract operations” with special behavior. But I couldn’t find any specs for how that is supposed to work, exactly, with `localStorage`. All that I could see are cursory mentions about behavior in specific browsers, and those are usually old and I presume obsolete.

So, in short: Is the detailed behavior of the `localStorage` specified anywhere?

Comment: Why is `length` a "special" property name in this context? *edit:* Oh, because `Storage` has a `length` property that returns the number of items... got it.

Comment: @FelixKling Likely because `Storage.length` is a computed property.

Comment: FWIW, Firefox does *not* return `length` when calling `Object.keys(...)` so I'd say implementations can do whatever they want as long as the conform to the interface definition (which doesn't say anything about own properties or how keys with the same name as API fields should be treated).